# Startup programs lock?

Tags: boot

I'm running XP professional with SP3. I was wondering if there are any free apps or programs that can lock my start-up programs. Like if a program tries to add a start-up item, it will notify me and let me choose if I want it to run or not.

It would be great it has the function that if I choose to block a program, it will never ask about it again. (Some programs try to add stuff every time I run it)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [Spybot Search and destroy](http://www.safer-networking.org/index2.html). It has an add-on called Tea-Timer which pops up with warnings whenever a system change is made.

Also, for any items that are already set, I advise you look at [Microsoft / Sysinternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[WinPatrol](http://www.winpatrol.com/) takes a snapshot of your critical system resources and alerts you to any changes that may occur without your knowledge.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mlin.net/ has a startup control panel and startup monitor which both let you control all startup apps, and will do exactly what you are asking for. You will be prompted for approval to add anything new to startup.

Comment: Link-> http://www.mlin.net/StartupMonitor.shtml